# How to fix "touch: out of range or illegal time specification" with touch t- function

Tags: shell

I have lost the creation date of 500 photos and clips when I transmitted them from my camera to my mac. Fortunately the creation dates are still in the files' name (like `P_20180615_131048_vHDR_Auto_HP.jpg` ; `V_20180616_071110_vHDR_Auto_OC0.mp4`).

So I read through some guidances from the internet to make the below scripts to help me batch changing the dates from the name. As I am a newbie of shell scripting, I don't know what I've done wrong.

```
for f in *; do
    t=“${f:2:4}${f:6:2}${f:8:2}${f:11:2}${f:13:2}.${f:15:2}”
    touch -t $t "$f"
done
```

I put the date in the format that touch needs(`201806151310.48`), but still get the same error

> "out of range or illegal time specification: [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS] [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]"

I've been tried to put a date in the script directly
touch like `-t 201806151610.48` $f and it worked. It seems that I cannot apply $t and $f both variables at the same time under touch function.

I would be very grateful if anyone can help me.

Comment: change it to `echo touch -t $t "$f"` so you can see what it produces.

Comment: More generally, generate the sequence of commands to a file  using `echo whatever > commandlist.sh`, then you can check the file with `vi commandlist.sh` and execute it using `sh < commandlist.sh`

Comment: What kind of shell you use? I tried to run your script, and it worked well. BTW, I use bash.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all of you. I solve the problem by just eliminate the " " in the second line. As I echo $t, it show "201806151310.48". How silly am i!! 
I use bash shell in Mac os, I wonder why Lester can run it smoothly.
BTW, happy new yearXD

Answer (score 0):

You've inadvertently put *smart quotes* in your Bash command. Compare the following lines:

```
t=“${f:2:4}${f:6:2}${f:8:2}${f:11:2}${f:13:2}.${f:15:2}”  # yours
t="${f:2:4}${f:6:2}${f:8:2}${f:11:2}${f:13:2}.${f:15:2}"  # corrected
```